# Does freezing fresh peppers, specifically habañero peppers ruin them?

Tags: freezing, chili-peppers

Someone gave me more peppers than I can eat and I'd like to freeze them for at least a few months, a year at most. Am I wasting good peppers by doing that?

Comment: You can definitely dry them, if you can't freeze them. I have dried birds-eye by just stiching them (with cotton) on to a wire and hanging it from a curtain rod. For a fleshier chilli I would sugest slitting them to help the moisture escape. 
You can also definitely pickle them.
I have no idea about freezing them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what you plan to use them for. They won't ever be crisp again after freezing, but if you're cooking them anyway, they will be fine. I do this all the time with leftover peppers.  You should certainly remove stems and seeds and cut them into whatever size you will need for cooking.

Comment: You don't even have to blanche them.  I tend to prep them a little before freezing - I cut off the stalk and remove the seeds, but only because it can get messy trying to do it after they thaw.  If you chop them you can use them from frozen.

Comment: @user23614: yes, certainly.  I've edited to include that.